# jQuery: how do I have different effects based on where you are in navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have this:

```
$('#mask').cycle({ 
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    timeout: 0, 
    speed:   300, 
    startingSlide: 0 
});
```

But there is a certain case where I want the fx to be scrollRight lets say when (myCondition == true)

how do I do that?

Comment: from where is that cycle plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work..

```
(myCondition == true) ? _fx = "scrollLeft" : _fx = "scrollRight";

$('#mask').cycle({ 
    fx: _fx,
    timeout: 0, 
    speed:   300, 
    startingSlide: 0 
});
```

It would be smarter to make an `_fx()` function, though..

```
function _fx(c) {
     return (c == true) ? "scrollLeft" : "scrollRight";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this:

```
var myFx = 'scrollLeft';
if( window.location.href.indexOf('myCondition=true') != -1 ) {
    myFx = 'scrollRight';
}

$('#mask').cycle({  
    fx: myFx,
    timeout: 0,  
    speed:   300,  
    startingSlide: 0  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and assuming that to scroll right you change `fx:` to scrollRight. In that case

```
if(myCondition == true) {
      $('#mask').cycle({
               fx: 'scrollRight',
               timeout: 0,
               speed: 300,
               startingSlide: 0
       });
} else {
      $('#mask').cycle({
               fx: 'scrollLeft',
               timeout: 0,
               speed: 300,
               startingSlide: 0
       });
}
```